# Joining data from tables mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The following tables form part of a database held in a relational DBMS:-

```
Hotel (hotelNo, hotelName, city)
Room (roomNo, hotelNo, type, price)
Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo)
Guest (guestNo, guestName, guestAddress)
```

where Hotel contains hotel details and hotelNo is the primary key;
Room contains room details for each hotel and (roomNo, hotelNo) forms the primary key;
Booking contains details of the bookings and (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom) forms the primary
key; Guest contains guest details and guestNo is the primary key.

If I wanted to **select the names and addresses of all the guests living in London**, what type of join would I have to use? From a logical point of view I've a theory that I have to work my way through all the tables, not just those that contain 'guestName', 'guestAddress' and 'city' but how to do this in a single query is confusing me.

Comment: It's just a 3-way inner join between the `Hotel`, `Booking`, and `Guest` tables. The `Room` table is unneeded for this.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I've never worked with this type of database before and thus there was really no logical place for me to begin despite several google searches.

Comment: sounds like a homework question?

Comment: Then look at the answer i posted :) it should do what you want

Comment: Thank you, apologies if this question seemed stupid, I'm new and still trying to figure out what's "stupid" to ask on here.

Comment: It's not stupid to ask questions.  This community likes to see a little effort from your side.  Just show your work on what you've tried in your question.  There are a lot of just "do my work for me" questions here and people don't appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have a query that intimidates you and requires multiple tables, it's best to break it into bits and piece it back together.

For example, the first part of your requirement is:

> Select the names and address of all the guests..

You can start by writing a query to do that. It's a simple select statement:

```
SELECT g.guestName, g.guestAddress
FROM guest g;
```

Next, you need to find guests that are living in London. Unfortunately, we can't jump straight to the `Hotel` table because it has no reference to `Guest`. However, `Booking` relates the two, so we can start by joining the booking table on the condition that the `guestNo` column matches, and then join the hotel table on the condition that `hotelNo` matches. Last, add a condition that the hotel is in London:

```
SELECT g.guestName, g.guestAddress
FROM guest g
JOIN booking b ON b.guestNo = g.guestNo
JOIN hotel h ON h.hotelNo = b.hotelNo AND h.city= 'London';
```

What this query does not do is protect against the situation where a guest has stayed at a hotel more than once. It seems that in this case you want guests who are *currently* living in London, so you can add another condition that `dateTo` is a date on or after today's date, like this:

```
SELECT g.guestName, g.guestAddress
FROM guest g
JOIN booking b ON b.guestNo = g.guestNo AND b.dateTo >= CURDATE();
JOIN hotel h ON h.hotelNo = b.hotelNo AND h.city= 'London';
```